# Does Kamailio automatically negotiate codec or do i had to set them manually

Tags: sip, voip, kamailio

I'm trying to connect to asterisk which belongs to vendor, the vendor says that my invite got rejected because codec is not PCMA/PCMU.
[image: sngrep]

as well as i need to set RTC port to 10K-40K to hear voice, while i plan to use RTCEngine later do i had to use it now?, since local call would still work without it.

so, can kamailio automatically negotiate and choose codec, (and probably RTC) on its own?.
since i was expecting that the sngrep didn't give every info i need to know, and the rejection was caused by something else. i believe they used asterisk 20.xx

Answer (score 1):

Kamailio do not negotiate any codec and not deal with SDP part(which have info about codecs) at all.

Kamailio do support ANY possible and not possible codec, just because it not deal with RTP.

You can deal with RTP using rtpproxy and "negotiate" codecs using SDPOPS module. Yes, you have add that code in your script, it is not in default script.

https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/devel/modules/sdpops.html

ps if you are using asterisk is waaay much simpler just allow asterisk do that.

Comment: i was looking the one with less resource usage while dealing with 1k phone per minute, a lot of monitoring, easy debug, etc. and what it does was just round-robin the invite away to third party (another service that use asterisk, etc). and people recommends kamailio for it. since deadline is coming, it felt its too late to change now. thanks

Comment: Kamailio is definitly NOT easy to debug :) For newcomers if you have to deal with RTP stream you have to use kamilio+asterisk or kamailio+freeswitch. It is possible negotiate codecs on SIP level like I described above, but it will give you nothing if you should transcode(kamailio can't)

Comment: A short note to let it be know that **Kamailio + RTPEngine** can do transcoding (Kamailio controls RTPEngine and can instruct it to do transcoding).

Comment: Yes, but it is not for beginning and has limitations. Mediaproxy also has mod